# Past Continuous or any other Past Tense?

Tags: past-tense, continuous

pls kindly advise if we should use here Past Continuous or any other Past tense?

e.g. I was waiting for you yesterday for 5 hours.

Situation: a person was waiting for another person. It lasted 5 hours. It was yesterday)

PS/ I've heard this sentence (word for word) from a teacher, who claims it is wrong to use here Past Continuous. Her variant is unknown. It was a video from her channel.

Thanks in advance)

Comment: The usual construction would be **I waited for you yesterday for five hours** (or: **I waited for you for five hours yesterday.** But you could easily frame a context in which you wanted to emphasise the length of time that you waited by using the past continuous. In this case you would usually drop the reference to the (**5 hours**) duration. So, it's not wrong. But it is unlikely and unusual.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. I think most people would would say:

*I was waiting for you for 5 hours yesterday.*

Because 5 hours is a long time to wait, I imagine this would be a strong complaint so I would expect the time to be emphasised, e.g.

*I was waiting for you for **5 hours** yesterday.*

or

*I was waiting for you for **5 whole hours** yesterday.*